# What does 'human and financial alike' modify?

Tags: usage

What does 'human and financial alike' modify in this passage?

**human and financial** are adjective, so I can infer that an omitted noun is **costs**, but I am not sure.

> The old maxim “I’ll sleep when I’m dead” is unfortunate. Adopt this
>   mind­set, and you will be dead sooner and the quality of that
>   (shorter) life will be worse. The elastic band of sleep deprivation
>   can stretch only so far before it snaps. Sadly, human beings are in
>   fact the only species that will deliberately deprive themselves of
>   sleep without legitimate gain. Every component of wellness, and
>   countless seams of societal fabric, are being eroded by our costly
>   state of sleep neglect: **human and financial alike**. So much so that
>   the World Health Organization (WHO) has now declared a sleep loss
>   epidemic throughout industrialized nations. It is no coincidence that
>   countries where sleep time has declined most dramatically over the
>   past century, such as the US, the UK, Japan, and South Korea, and
>   several in Western Europe, are also those suffering the greatest
>   increase in rates of physical diseases and mental disorders.
>
> Source: [Why We Sleep: Unlocking the Power of Sleep and Dreams
>   By Matthew Walker](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=ZlU3DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=Every+component+of+wellness,+and+countless+seams+of+societal+fabric,+are+being+eroded+by+our+costly+state+of+sleep+neglect:+human+and+financial+alike.&source=bl&ots=MVPacD0WfT&sig=ACfU3U0cRRkwoZ0rMN6hQQCLld6dY_T1kg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiL_ojXhabhAhUQxosBHWzzCrkQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Every%20component%20of%20wellness%2C%20and%20countless%20seams%20of%20societal%20fabric%2C%20are%20being%20eroded%20by%20our%20costly%20state%20of%20sleep%20neglect%3A%20human%20and%20financial%20alike.&f=false0)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The words "human" and "financial" modify the word "cost" in this sentence:

> our **cost**ly state of sleep neglect: **human** and **financial** alike.

Essentially it is saying that *sleep neglect* has both *a human cost* and *a financial cost*. Sleep neglect could lead to some financial cost or loss; but also have a detrimental effect on a person, perhaps on their health.

This is using the wider definition of the word "cost"; namely *the effort, loss, or sacrifice necessary to achieve or obtain something*.

Answer (score 2):

*Cost* is not a noun present in that sentence, nor anywhere in that quote. The nouns or noun phrases that it might seem to be are:

- "every component of wellness"
- "wellness"
- "countless seams of societal fabric"
- "societal fabric"
- "sleep neglect

Phrased like that, it should be the (or a) subject of the principal verb, *eroded*. Thus, it should be wellness/"every component of wellness", or "societal fabric"/"countless seams of societal fabric", or potentially both. Really, the meaning is sufficiently wooly that it doesn't matter which - it is saying that both **human *and* financial** 'components' and/or 'seams' are being eroded by sleep neglect.

Comment: tl;dr - the paragraph quoted by the OP is a hot mess.

Answer (score 0):

> *Every component of wellness, and countless seams of societal fabric*,
>   *are being eroded by our costly state of sleep neglect: human and*
>   *financial alike*.

I'd be inclined to say that "human and financial alike" is post-modifying "our costly state of sleep neglect". It's sleep neglect that is costly  in both human and financial terms.